# Can AWS Lambda be used to achieve my performance requirements, if so how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a requirement where a single API request generates 1000 individual independent tasks.

Today we run as a C application in a single [c5.9xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) EC2 instance and share the tasks across all the threads on the EC2 instance.

The tasks:

1. Are 100% cpu bound, there is no I/O or external interaction, they do a lot of calculations.
2. Are 100% independent, there is no relationship/dependancy between the tasks when they are executing.
3. Only use a small amount of memory.
4. On completion, generate some output. The output from all the tasks is merged/consolidated into a single response payload which is less than 3kb in size in json.

The response payload must include 100% of the tasks, there is no tolerance for missing task outputs.

With the current architecture ignoring network hops the processing time is less than 1.5 seconds.

I am considering porting this to AWS Lambda because:

1. The requests are sparse/intermittent with significant periods of inactivity
2. Lambda may be cheaper - When I take into account dev, test, qa and production, etc the cost for EC2 instances becomes a problem
3. Lambda may be more scaleable - Under the current architecture a single EC2 instance is required to process a single request. If I want to process 7 requests concurrently (during a period of bust activity) I would need to have 7 EC2 instances provisioned. Given my 1.5 seconds response time, I don't see dynamic ec2 scaling as helpful in this instance.
4. Perhaps with Lambda I can either improve my performance (reduce the response time down from 1.5 seconds) OR increase my calculation accuracy by running even more than 1000 tasks but still within 1.5 seconds.

I realise that the AWS Lambda supported languages [(Java, Go, PowerShell, Node.js, C#, Python, and Ruby code)](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Lambda%20natively%20supports%20Java,%2C%20C%23%2C%20Go%20and%20PowerShell.), are unlikely to be as fast as C, however I think with some focussed optimisation the difference in processing time for a task will be minor and more than made up for by the greater potential concurrency of Lambda. I am happy to use any language. To be honest the focus of this question is not around the selection of the language, rather the architecture. I do realise that different language implementation will have different characteristics [regarding startup time and execution time](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/).

My initial idea is to fan-out each task to run as an individual Lambda, then merge the results.

I noticed [this article](https://medium.com/circuitpeople/patterns-for-aws-lambda-fanout-a7662bb0b2aa) with the author describing a roughly 50ms blocking delay on just the invocation of **await lambda.InvokeAsync()**. That in itself is potentially a show stopper for my performance requirements.

I also wondered if I should use a queue based architecture by writing 1000 task request messages to a queue and allowing 1000 Lambda's to be triggered to process them concurrently. However then I need to merge the results, presumably by writing all the outputs to another SQS, where a results processor can merge them. I will actually have multiple requests running concurrently so the architecture needs to scale to support that.

I understand that by default AWS Lambda is [restricted to 1000 concurrent invocations per account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), however I understand that this can be increased by asking AWS support.

As you can see there are considerable unknowns, is AWS Lambda likely to work in the end for my performance requirement (1000 tasks in 1.5 seconds), if so, what is the recommended architecture, particularly in regards to the fanout-gather of responses.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I will give reddit a go too.